# Very slow connections to ArcSDE with over 20,000 datasets

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase

I have a problem with ArcSDE that I have never come accross before and I was wondering if anyone could shed any light on this problem.

**Problem ArcSDE 9.3.1:**

> Connnecting to an ArcSDE instance (Oracle Spatial) with over 20,000
>   datasets (raster) causes ArcGIS/ArcObjects code to connect very slowly - minutes in fact before a successful connection is made to the database.  However if a native SQL connection is made, the connection is almost instant.

Has anyone else had this problem and if so what can be done to remedy this problem.

Comment: Are you storing your rasters in a [Raster Catalog](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t00000030000000)?

Comment: Probably a better description of the connection strings and particulars of the keyword datatype would be beneficial.

Comment: Not sure until I get to the client site - but I'm guessing they are just plain loaded into ArcSDE without any configuration.

Comment: I will get back to you with more details when I get to the client site too...maybe I was jumping the gun a bit too much here :)

Comment: Actually, I remember, they are loaded into the database as blobs - so each tile is a blob, I don't think they use raster catalogs at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are they registered with the GeoDatabase and in A Raster Catalog? If not, it basically has to dynamically find info about each table and 20,000 DB DESCRIBEs can get kind of heavy and time consuming :)

Comment: ahh interesting.  This has given me some things to think about - hopefully it should be a fairly easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

We had a noticeable speed improvement when we switched our users over to [Direct Connections](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Making_a_direct_connection_from_ArcGIS_Desktop_to_a_geodatabase_in_Oracle/002n00000039000000/).